# Is it okay to put the nav tag outside of the header tag?

Tags: html, tags

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Scarface</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
     </head>
     <body>
       <div class="wrapper">
         <header>
           <h1>The World Is Yours</h1>
         </header>
         <nav>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
           <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </nav>
       </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Is it okay if I put my nav tag outside of the header tag? I know many people/developers like to have the navigation "wrapped" inside of their header tags. Thank you in advance for any help with my question.

Comment: It is correct to place this in the `header` or `body` tag. Note. The `<head>` is not the same as `<header>`. [read more](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-nav-element.html#the-nav-element)

Comment: thank you jbutler, but is it okay to place the nav tag outside of the header tag? I usually see the nav tag "nested" inside the header tag. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly valid html. the second demo in my link gives an example of that

Comment: Thank you so much jbutler, I really appreciate your help. Sorry I didn't see the "read more". Thanks again.

Comment: `<header>`, `<nav>` `<article>`, `<main>`, etc are just plain `<div>`s. They are only named so it is easier to follow your HTML structure when reading your code. They do not "do" anything special.

Comment: Thank you Gendame, much appreciated.

Comment: @Gendarme Strictly speaking, HTML is only about semantics. The special rendering of some elements is not required by the spec. And from the point of view of semantics, `<header>` `<nav>` `<article>` `<main>` and `<div>` are completely different.